# Does Hasura support "contains" filter for integer[] data types from postgres?

Tags: postgresql, filter, graphql, hasura, postgraphile

We are evaluating a migration from postgraphile to hasura and what I've noticed is that hasura doesn't support a `contains` filter option for a view column of type `integer[]`.

Is there a way to enable this? We have several views depending on the `contains` filter.

We are using postgres12 and hasura 2.20.1

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by setting the column type in Hasura to JSONB... the integer array is a valid JSON type and then you can query it like this:

```
query MyQuery {
  test_table(where: {int_json: {_contains: 2}}) {
    int_json
  }
}
```

and you will get a response like this:

```json
{
  "data": {
    "test_table": [
      {
        "int_json": [
          1,
          2,
          3,
          4
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```